# Create trigger using Room Database(Room Persistence Library)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

How to "**Create Trigger**" using Room Persistence library

```
CREATE TRIGGER  IF NOT EXISTS delete_till_10 INSERT ON user WHEN (select count(*) from user)>9

BEGIN 

    DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN  (SELECT id FROM user ORDER BY id limit (select count(*) -9 from user));

END
```

Comment: Room abstracts away raw SQL. You are supposed to handle objects.

Answer (score 17):

Call `getOpenHelper()` on your `RoomDatabase`. This gives you a `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper`, which has an API reminiscent of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. On there, call `getWritableDatabase()` to get a `SupportSQLiteDatabase`, and on there use `execSQL()` to execute your SQL statements. A `RoomDatabase.Callback` is one place to execute this sort of SQL, as AdamMc331 illustrates in [this Kotlin snippet](https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/5d48220875ce6b8bf0a0c0396ec8a0c0).

In other words, Room does not really help with this scenario, but you can always work with the lower-level database API for cases like this one.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations about when we should do this? Triggers can only be created once, so I would assume that doing it in a room migration is good, but wanted your opinion.

Comment: Adding on, though, even if I did it in a migration, where should I define a trigger so that it is applied when an app is first installed?

Comment: @AdamMc331: I don't know how to do a migration for the initial creation of a database. So while you would need to use a migration for an update to an existing app, you would need to do it somewhere else for the initial creation. This might be a use case [for `RoomDatabase.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Callback.html); you would create the trigger in `onCreate()`. You attach a `Callback` via `addCallbacks()` on the `RoomDatabase.Builder`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I just tested briefly and looks great. I've put the relevant code in a gist for anyone who may stumble on this, feel free to add it to your answer - https://gist.github.com/AdamMc331/5d48220875ce6b8bf0a0c0396ec8a0c0