# How to reset previously updated rows and update the selected rows with only one query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table that for the specified rows with specified ids need to change the value, while for previously selected rows should be reset. 
Do I need to reset the whole table and then update for specified rows. is there any option to update table with only one query. 
I'm using room persistence on android

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Like any database standard, Room Update and Delete are separate operation types.

Then maybe you can try to execute Trigger if you need mixed operation ([thread about trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628649/create-trigger-using-room-databaseroom-persistence-library)).

But for what reason do you have to execute this two operations in a same query ?