# Room Persistence Library - CREATE VIEW

Tags: android-room

I need to use a SQL VIEW in a query using Room Persistence Library.

Using Commonsware's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45633544/1703943) I've been able to run a raw SQL statement to create the view during DB creation.

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
            .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW view_name " +
                            "AS SELECT [...] "
                    );
                }
            })
            .build();
```

The VIEW is actually created on the SQLite DB and works fine, but I cannot refer to the it in my Dao's @Query because I get a compile-time error:

> Error:(100, 48) error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: view_name)

Any idea on how to let Room to know about my view or to ignore the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 17/12/2018**

Version 2.1.0 and higher of the Room persistence library now provides support for SQLite database views:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views
(see D-D's comment)

**UPDATE 15/12/2017**

Be aware that this solution actually breaks DB migrations.

Problem is with the Entity primary key that obviously doesn't exist on the view, so migration is not valid.

See [CommonsWare's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452786/room-persistence-library-create-view#comment82634506_46464189) for a possible hacky workaround.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It seems that this is not possible at the moment using Room.

Anyway I've done it using a workaround: I've created an Entity with the same name and columns as the view (only the name is actually mandatory), this will create a table on DB and allow you to use that table name in queries without compile-time errors.

Then during Room DB creation I DROP this entity's table just before the CREATE VIEW.

```
Room
    .databaseBuilder(context, DueDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
    .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
          super.onCreate(db);
          //Drop the fake table and create a view with the same name
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE view_name");
          db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW view_name " +
                     "AS SELECT [...]"
          );
       }
    })
    .build();
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I didn't see an issue already filed for this, so [I added one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67033276).

Comment: @CommonsWare please see my update to the answer, it seems my solution make migrations impossible.
Do you have any advice?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised that you're running into problems, though I had some hope that perhaps your workaround would hold up. About the only thing that I can think of is to have your migration drop the view and create a suitable entity table, plus make a note somewhere that triggers you to revert that after the migration has run (e.g., in an `onOpen()` method on a `RoomDatabase.Callback`). Even if that would work, that's a hack on the side of your existing hack, and this is starting to get scary. :-(

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are proposing and I was trying something similar before giving up.
It is becoming very hacky and I prefer to get rid of the DB views until Room get proper support for them.
As always thank you CommonsGuy

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views